# Azure B2C: After successful authentication of user, correct redirecting URL is being picked and getting AADB2C90205 error

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure B2C for SSO. It is a multi-tenant setup with custom policies. I can get the token when tested with a redirect URL as https://jwt.ms. When using a redirect URL as my application URL (https://sso.app.com/billing/default.aspx) it lands on the Microsoft email page. After giving the username, password, and MFA acceptance, it shows user authentication is successful. But, when it goes to my application URL by picking in redirect URL, Getting the below error:

AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation

Answer (score 0):

The error "***"AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation"***  usually occurs if the Azure B2C application do not have required permissions or scope to perform the action or to call the web api.

**To resolve the error,** create a web API and configure the scopes like below:

[image]

For ***sample***, generated  **tokens** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/APIID/user.readapi offline_access openid
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Now make use of the access token to call your web Api.

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

- Make sure to grant the admin consent to the Api permissions granted to the application.
- Make sure to decode the access token and check whether the required scope is displayed in access token via [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/)
- Make sure to pass scope as `https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/ApiId/scope name`. while generating the access token.

**Reference:**

[Error code reference - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes)

Comment: Still seeing the same error. Authentication is successful, but when redirecting to my application URL, it is giving the 404 error  - AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.

Comment: I dont even need a concept of 'Exposing an API' and providing permissions. Even If I try, its giving a different error after successful authentication during redirection to my Application URL - AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance

Comment: What API are you trying to call?

Comment: Is 'Expose API' option required as mandatory?. Azure B2C SSO should work without expoing any API and creating permissions. My application is .net based hoated on IIS. The setup working for one customer but not working in another.